# Git submodules vs Mercurial subrepositories--significant differences?

Tags: git, mercurial

My team is thinking about switching from Mercurial to Git.  Our current Mercurial setup uses subrepositories.  My impression, after playing around a little bit with Git submodules, is that Git submodules and Mercurial subrepositories are pretty much the same--they allow you to point commits in one repository to commits in another.

Are there any differences between the two that would cause problems when switching between the VCS's?

Comment: As far as I know, there are none, but I have not made much use of Mercurial subrepositories.

Answer (score 2):

In *some rare* case - yes

- Mercurial's subrepos can be HG/Git/SVN. I can say nothng about SVN-submodules, but HG doesn't supported in Git anyway
- `[subpaths]` feature of Mercurial in order to remapping subrepos in tree doesn't have any replacement in Git